# How to make RegEx more performant?

Tags: java, regex, performance, scala

In my code I'm doing a regex match case in Scala like this:

```
line match {
    case regexp(unix_time, elapsed, remotehost, code_status, bytes, method, url, rfc931, peerstatus_peerhost, file_type) => 
        LogLine(getHumanDate(unix_time), elapsed, remotehost, code_status, bytes, method, url, rfc931, peerstatus_peerhost, file_type)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse row: " + line)
}
```

I'm using this regex pattern.

```
val regexp = """(\d{9,10}\.\d{3})\s*(\d+) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\w+\/\d+) (\d+) (\w+) (\S+) (\-) (\w+\/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\w+\/\-) (\S+)""".r
```

I'm interested in making it more performant. I got it working with this but it's not very fast and I guess it can be done better.

Here are some sample log lines that needs to match:

```
1393930710.739 278 192.168.1.20 TCP_MISS/200 5848 GET http://www.coderanch.com/templates/default/images/quote.gif - HIER_DIRECT/145.20.133.81 text/plain

1393930719.989 73 192.168.178.27 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 268805 GET http://sunny:8080/viewapp/classpath/jquery.js - HIER_NONE/- application/x-javascript

1393997284.209  59287 192.168.1.2 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT 172.104.89.123:5228 - HIER_NONE/- -
```

Comment: What do you actually *do* with the knowledge of "line matches the regex or not"?

Comment: You should replace all * by + if it fits. Make as less options as possible.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all of the length qualifiers with `+`?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html has some good info on regex performance

Comment: For the IP addresses, you should consider just using `\d+` for the pattern. If somebody is feeding you funky IP addresses, you can catch that later on.

Comment: @BobDalgleish - That actually doesn't make a difference in my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unlikely to get much faster using regex matching since even just splitting on spaces:

```
def split_apart(line: String) = line.split("""\s+""") match {
  case Array(unix_time, elapsed, remotehost, code_status, bytes, method, url, rfc931, peerstatus_peerhost, file_type) =>
    (unix_time, elapsed, remotehost, code_status, bytes, method, url, rfc931, peerstatus_peerhost, file_type)
  case _ => throw new Exception(":(")
}
```

takes 60% of the time of the full regex match.

If you are absolutely sure you have to care about this, then you will need to do it by hand.  Something like this is about 6x faster (on Java6 where substring doesn't actually copy the string data; I haven't checked 7):

```
def parse(line: String) = {
  def fail(s: String) = throw new Exception("Could not parse '"+s+"' in "+line)
  def checkA(s: String) = {
    if (s.length < 13 || s.length > 14 || s(s.length-4) != '.') fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length-4) { if (!s(i).isDigit) fail(s); i += 1 }
    i += 1
    while (i < s.length) { if (!s(i).isDigit) fail(s); i += 1 }
    s
  }
  def checkB(s: String) = {
    if (s.length == 0) fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length) { if (!s(i).isDigit) fail(s); i += 1 }
    s
  }
  def checkC(s: String) = {
    if (s.length < 7) fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < 1 || i > 3 || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    var j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < j+1 || i > j+3 || i >= s.length || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < j+1 || i > j+3 || i >= s.length || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i != s.length) fail(s)
    s
  }
  def checkD(s: String) = {
    if (s.length < 3) fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length && { var c = s(i); c.isLetterOrDigit || c=='_' }) i += 1
    if (i+1 >= s.length || !(s(i)=='/')) fail(s)
    i += 1
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i != s.length) fail(s)
    s
  }
  def checkE(s: String) = checkB(s)
  def checkF(s: String) = {
    if (s.length < 0) fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length) { var c = s(i); if (!(c.isLetterOrDigit || c=='_')) fail(s); i += 1 }
    s
  }
  def checkG(s: String) = s
  def checkH(s: String) = { if (s != "-") fail(s); s }
  def checkI(s: String): String = {
    if (s.length < 3) fail(s)
    var i = 0
    while (i < s.length && { var c = s(i); (c.isLetterOrDigit || c=='_') }) i += 1
    if (i+1 >= s.length || !(s(i)=='/')) fail(s)
    i += 1
    if (s(i) == '-' && i+1 == s.length) return s
    var j = i
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < j+1 || i > j+3 || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < j+1 || i > j+3 || i >= s.length || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i < j+1 || i > j+3 || i >= s.length || s(i) != '.') fail(s)
    j = i+1
    i = j
    while (i < s.length && s(i).isDigit) i += 1
    if (i != s.length) fail(s)
    s
  }
  def checkJ(s: String) = s
  val cs = line
  val a0 = 0
  var a1 = 0
  while (a0 < line.length && !cs(a1).isWhitespace) a1 += 1
  var b0 = a1+1
  while (b0 < line.length && cs(b0).isWhitespace) b0 += 1
  var b1 = b0+1
  while (b1 < line.length && !cs(b1).isWhitespace) b1 += 1
  val c0 = b1+1
  var c1 = c0+1
  while (c1 < line.length && !cs(c1).isWhitespace) c1 += 1
  val d0 = c1+1
  var d1 = d0+1
  while (d1 < line.length && !cs(d1).isWhitespace) d1 += 1
  val e0 = d1+1
  var e1 = e0+1
  while (e1 < line.length && !cs(e1).isWhitespace) e1 += 1
  val f0 = e1+1
  var f1 = f0+1
  while (f1 < line.length && !cs(f1).isWhitespace) f1 += 1
  val g0 = f1+1
  var g1 = g0+1
  while (g1 < line.length && !cs(g1).isWhitespace) g1 += 1
  val h0 = g1+1
  var h1 = h0+1
  while (h1 < line.length && !cs(h1).isWhitespace) h1 += 1
  val i0 = h1+1
  var i1 = i0+1
  while (i1 < line.length && !cs(i1).isWhitespace) i1 += 1
  val j0 = i1+1
  var j1 = j0+1
  while (j1 < line.length && !cs(j1).isWhitespace) j1 += 1
  ( checkA(line.substring(a0,a1)),
    checkB(line.substring(b0,b1)),
    checkC(line.substring(c0,c1)),
    checkD(line.substring(d0,d1)),
    checkE(line.substring(e0,e1)),
    checkF(line.substring(f0,f1)),
    checkG(line.substring(g0,g1)),
    checkH(line.substring(h0,h1)),
    checkI(line.substring(i0,i1)),
    checkJ(line.substring(j0,j1))
  ) 
}
```

But you'd better really, really care about that 6x speedup in order to do it this way.  This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: OMG! Sometimes I miss the forest for the trees. ;) Of course the split option... Works much better! Thanks for all the valuable information on the matter. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to match lines, the first improvement you can do is to use the start of line anchor `^` (that will make the pattern fail faster)

```
^(\d{9,10}\.\d{3})\s*(\d+) (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (\w+/\d+) (\d+) (\w+) (\S+) (-) (\w+/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\w+/-) (\S+)
```

(I have removed all uneeded escape). An other thing you can do is to remove uneeded capturing groups (I'm not sure that `(-)` is very useful) and try to put the end of line anchor `$`

Comment: On the examples given, plus one half-match, plus one complete non-match, I see no significant difference in my microbenchmarks.  When using only valid strings, I also see no significant difference.

Comment: You can't see a difference with a so small string. To see something you must try it with a big string.

Comment: These aren't matching big strings.

Answer (score 0):

not sure you can really gain performance keeping a unique regexp. if you don't really need to check every parts format, it might be faster if you parse using .split(" ") and then check result length and only potentially malformated parts...